# an alternative to progressbar?

Tags: loading, message

could anybody knows any alternatives to progressbar?
Inmy project im using progressbar..I would like to change it to something like a rotating gif image which indicates the processing or someother labels which prevents the user from interacting to the program.I tried to implement the gif image by using background worker but its hanging may be coz of huge file transfer process..
So im searching for someother alternative like a label which will disable the content and prevent the user to interact with the program.
Could anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Circular Progress Bar](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/sql2005circularprogress.aspx)